# How to check whether date widget is empty?

Tags: validation, date, widget, plone

I tried to check whether date widget is empty. If it is empty, it shouldn't show up.

```
<div class="field" 
    tal:define="value widget/value;
                valueexists python:value not in (None, '',);
                label widget/label"
    tal:condition="python:widget.__name__ not in ('IBasic.title', 'IBasic.description', 'title', 'description',) and valueexists">
```

Problem is the below expression doesn't seem able to check for date:

```
python:value not in (None, '',)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "can't check for date"? What is 'value' in your case?

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
<div class="field" 
tal:define="value       widget/value;
            label       widget/label"
tal:condition="python:widget.__name__ not in ('IBasic.title', 'IBasic.description', 
  'title', 'description',) and value">
...
</div>
```

Testing for *specific* values of widget/value seems destined to cause trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question correctly, but I'd also like to suggest jQuery as a way to check and conditionally hide (remove) a widget, if it's for aesthetic reasons.